# Vue npm run serve Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH

Tags: linux, vue.js, ubuntu, nginx, npm

I get:

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH chunk-vendors.js:1
```

in Google Chrome console and blank page when trying to load Vue development page started via:

```
user@ubuntu:~# npm run serve

 DONE  Compiled successfully in 11909ms   
  App running at:
  - Local:   http://(my_public_ip):5008/
  - Network: http://(my_public_ip):5008/

  Note that the development build is not optimized.
  To create a production build, run npm run build.
```

What I have tried up to now:

1.

```
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n 7.0
// also remember to update npm
sudo npm update -g npm 
sudo npm cache clean -force 
npm cache verify
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/npm /usr/local/share/man/man1/node* ~/.npm
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/node*
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/node*
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/include/node*
```

2. 

```
sudo apt-get purge nodejs npm
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt-get install npm nodejs
```

3. Tried to load the page in incognito mode (with no cache)

Nothing worked for me.

Everything was working great a few weeks ago. No settings have been changed. Nothing global installed or removed on the server.

`lsof` result is:

```
root@ubuntu:~# sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN
systemd-r   855 systemd-resolve   13u  IPv4  22732      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.53:53 (LISTEN)
sshd        935            root    3u  IPv4  24127      0t0  TCP *:22 (LISTEN)
sshd        935            root    4u  IPv6  24129      0t0  TCP *:22 (LISTEN)
nginx       940            root    6u  IPv4  25804      0t0  TCP *:5001 (LISTEN)
nginx       940            root    7u  IPv4  25805      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
nginx       940            root    8u  IPv6  25806      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
nginx       942        www-data    6u  IPv4  25804      0t0  TCP *:5001 (LISTEN)
nginx       942        www-data    7u  IPv4  25805      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
nginx       942        www-data    8u  IPv6  25806      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
nginx       943        www-data    6u  IPv4  25804      0t0  TCP *:5001 (LISTEN)
nginx       943        www-data    7u  IPv4  25805      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
nginx       943        www-data    8u  IPv6  25806      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
postgres    992        postgres    3u  IPv4  24408      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:5432 (LISTEN)
node      25318            user   19u  IPv4 153059      0t0  TCP (my_public_ip):5008 (LISTEN)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It's related to a timeout error that can be solved using this setup

On the file: **vue.config.js**

```
module.exports = {

  devServer: {
    proxy: {
      '/*': {
        target: 'http://localhost:8080',
        secure: false,
        prependPath: false,
        proxyTimeout: 1000 * 60 * 10,
        timeout: 1000 * 60 * 10
      }
    }
  }
  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It was solved by itself. I came back to it after a day and it worked like it used to work.

I have no idea what was the reason.