# Getting net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH 200 (OK) when running Vue project

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, vue-component, vue-router

I have the following problem, my vue project used to run properly and not out of the blue it is giving me the error
`net:: ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH 200 (OK)` for the `chunk-vendors.js` file in my Chrome console. Only the index page is visible and I am unable to access any routes.

Here is the vue.config.js file

```
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  lintOnSave: false,
  configureWebpack: {
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /.html$/,
          loader: 'vue-template-loader',
          exclude: /index.html/,
        },
      ],
    },
    optimization: {
      minimizer: [new UglifyJsPlugin()],
      splitChunks: {
        chunks: 'all',
      },
    },
    plugins: [
      // Ignore all locale files of moment.js
      new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/^\.\/locale$/, /moment$/),
    ],
  },
};
```

These are the dependencies and devDependencies that i am using in this project.

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@rxweb/reactive-forms": "^1.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.6.0",
    "bootstrap-vue": "^2.21.2",
    "core-js": "^3.16.0",
    "luxon": "^1.28.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^1.2.7",
    "vue": "^2.6.14",
    "vue-class-component": "^7.2.3",
    "vue-datetime": "^1.0.0-beta.14",
    "vue-property-decorator": "^8.4.2",
    "vue-router": "^3.5.2",
    "vue-template-loader": "^1.0.0",
    "weekstart": "^1.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^2.33.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^2.33.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^4.5.13",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^4.5.13",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "^4.5.13",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-typescript": "^4.5.13",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^4.5.13",
    "@vue/eslint-config-typescript": "^5.0.2",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^6.2.2",
    "lint-staged": "^9.5.0",
    "node-sass": "^5.0.0",
    "sass-loader": "^10.1.0",
    "typescript": "^3.9.10",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.14"
  },
```

I have tried adding proxy to the dev server as described in this post [Vue npm run serve Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63245310/vue-npm-run-serve-failed-to-load-resource-neterr-content-length-mismatch/64688021) but still the problem persists.
I checked the network tab and the chunk-vendor.js file was over 11.4 MB.
I am using Vue 2.6.14